# What weights for a multi-part benchmark?

Tags: c++, c, benchmarking

I'm writing a benchmark for a school project. It's very simple but I am wondering, in real life, what are the typical weights used for the various types of benchmarks? For instance, if I am combining an integer test, a cache test, a floating point test, should they be equally weighted in the final "score"? My hunch is that for many things, the cache test matters more than raw arithmetic, and that for many things, the RAM speed is a big factor. Is there a consensus?

Comment: Be specific.  As currently presented, this question has no answer.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no universal set of weights.**

Different real-world workloads have different bottlenecks, or different weightings.

**There is no single number that can tell you how fast a computer is.**  It's possible (and happens in real life) that program X runs faster on computer A then B, but program Y runs faster on computer B.

Choosing a set of weights for microbenchmarks totally comes down to what *you* want your number to mean, and what kind of workload you want it to be a rough indicator for.

---

e.g. a dense matmul can usually saturate FMA execution unit throughput because it does O(N^3) work over N^2 data.  With careful cache-blocking you can get mostly L1d cache hits, and avoid doing more than 1 SIMD vector load per FMA.  DRAM / cache bandwidth has to be high enough to keep up, but most of the stores/reloads hit in L1d cache (which of course also has to be able to keep up).

But other workloads might bottleneck on memory bandwidth or latency and not care about FPU throughput at all.  e.g. AMD Ryzen 1 can do 1x 128-bit FMA per clock while Intel Haswell and later can do 2x 256-bit FMA per clock.  But Ryzen is faster or nearly equal clock-for-clock for some other workloads.

And on multi-core systems some programs are single-threaded and care only about single-core throughput, while others scale well and get a big speedup on a machine with lots of slower cores.  Or they might care about inter-core latency vs. aggregate memory bandwidth.